# Retain Stored Password After Hostname chnages

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have setup some testing database VM on Cloud, and use MySQL Workbench to modified the database for testing.

The problem is, When I always shutdown my VM after use to reduce cost, and the **IP is going to changed every day**.

And when I **change hostname** in [Edit Connection], the **password is going to be erased**. So I need to re-enter the same password every time.

My question is, when I do [Edit Connection > Change Hostname], is there any way to make **password not be reset**? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Basically after "Right Client" -> "Edit Connection", and changed the hostname.

You need to not click "Test Connection", instead just click Close, the hostname will changed and password is retained.

This method is working on MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE